# Issue with generating JUnit HTML report?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am new to Maven, I run my pom.xml through "maven install". Every thing is working fine and also build is getting succeed but HTML reports are not getting generated.

I read some article that Run "mvn site" to generate this html report. But How can I run my tests by mvn site.

Can any one explain why we use and how to use the "mvn site".

Comment: Have you tried just run it?

Comment: I tried, but my maven installation path is in "C" directory , my workspace directory is in "E" directory. How can I run mvn site command from "C" directory which will refer the POM.xml which is located in "E:/TestProject/POM.xml"? please help me

Comment: Is there any way to run mvn site through eclipse by using any configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the goal "site" in run configurations,

Screen shot is as follows,

[image]

And run my pom.xml through mvn site.